# Input Validation w/ numbers&strings

Tags: c++, string, validation, input

So I have just learnt input validation however I ran into a problem. I'm forcing the user to enter a number and not a string which works, however if the user enter a number (one that is included in the switch case) and a string then the program crashes. Any tips on what to change so the validation works on everything?

```
    int menu(double pi)                                                             //menu for choosing a shape
{
    int choice = 0;
    cout << "Please select what you wish to calculate:\n\n1 - Area of a Circle\n\n2 - Circumference of a Circle\n\n3 - Area of a Rectangle\n\n4 - Area of a Triangle\n\n5 - Volume of a Cuboid\n\n ";
    while (!(cin >> choice))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, please enter a number of 1-5\n\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    }
    system("CLS");

     switch (choice)                                                                //switch case for each shape
        {
        case 1:
            circleArea(pi);
            break;
        case 2:
            circleCircum(pi);
            break;
        case 3:
            rectanArea();
            break;
        case 4:
            triangArea();
            break;
        case 5:
            cubVol();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input! Please try again.\n\n";
            break;
        }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typically if you want bullet proof code you need to read the input in as a string and then parse and convert it to what you want.

Comment: Uh, I sort of get what you mean although not quite, if it isn't a problem, would you mind providing some example code? I'm still kinda a noob to programming, started in September

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using

```
cin >> choice
```

When inputting a number is that `>>` will stop at the first non-numeric input and as long as there was numeric input to begin with it will treat it as a valid read.  That means things like `2L`, `2.0`, and `-1T` are all valid integer inputs as far as `cin` is concerned.  It just leaves the invalid part in the stream.  It is this remaining steam input that messes up the program on the next input operation.

One way to fix this is to read the input into a `std::string` using `getline` and then parse the string to make sure it contains valid input.  If you want to get a `int` for instance the

```
int choice;
std::string input;
std::size_t pos;
do
{
    std::cout << "Enter Choice: ";
    std::getline(cin,input);
    choice = stoi(input, &pos);
} while(pos != input.size());
```

This makes sure that you read in everything up to the pressing enter into `input` and that you only stop the loop once everything entered can be converted to a valid `int`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I tried implementing this into my program but getline & stoi are unidentified. Are there any additional libraries I should be using or? (just using <iostream>)

Comment: @PinkieBarto You need `<string>` for them